# magento 2.1 why static content deploy after every setup:upgrade

Tags: magento-2.1

I have installed `Magento 2.1.0` successfully and also created many modules.

Suddenly after every `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command , its not generating static contents.

The problem is after every `setup:upgrade` needs to have static content deploy command otherwise no CSS and JS works. If anyone can suggest me for a solution and the reason would be appreciable.

deploy mode is : developer

Comment: in Magento documentation:
Developer mode:Static view files are not cached; they are written to the Magento pub/static directory every time they’re called

Comment: Thank w.k, Yes if mode is set to developer then it must auto generate static content but that is the issue here. even though mode is set to developer static content are not auto generating after every upgrade command.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with you here in terms of needing to do this each time.

I am called to run setup:static-content:deploy with each upgrade and I have two languages so I need to run with the locale flag next to it, ie:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US <other locals>
```

However, we do have the option of **--keep-generated** with **setup:upgrade**. See the help:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade --help
Usage:
 setup:upgrade [--keep-generated] [--magento-init-params="..."]

Options:
 --keep-generated       Prevents generated files from being deleted. 
                        We discourage using this option except when deploying to production. 
                        Consult your system integrator or administrator for more information.
 --magento-init-params  Add to any command to customize Magento initialization parameters
                        For example: "MAGE_MODE=developer&MAGE_DIRS[base][path]=/var/www/example.com&MAGE_DIRS[cache][path]=/var/tmp/cache"
 --help (-h)            Display this help message
 --quiet (-q)           Do not output any message
 --verbose (-v|vv|vvv)  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
 --version (-V)         Display this application version
 --ansi                 Force ANSI output
 --no-ansi              Disable ANSI output
 --no-interaction (-n)  Do not ask any interactive question
```

It will keep static content.

Answer (score 1):

setup:upgrade wipes everything. It is like manually emptying the generated, pub, and cache folders. If you do not deploy again, there won't be any files to build from.

Answer (score 0):

To regenerate the static content (html, css, js) the command is:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

This will generate the static assets under *pub/static*.

Otherwise you can combine 2 commands with **&&**:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

This will concatenate the 2 commands in 1, in particular if the first one is successful the second will be executed.

Comment: Elio thanks but you have not understood my question. I know this command is used to generated static contents.But my problem is whenever I run "php bin/magento setup:upgrade"  command, it is also needed to run command - "php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy" to generate css and js which is time taking. If I run "php bin/magento setup:upgrade" it should not ask for "php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy" , what action should be taken for it.

Comment: hi @SPK see my updated answer if can solve your question.